# Why is my SVG animation looking differently on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, next.js, tsx

Here is my current SVG Code:

```
<svg
    className='flex w-full h-[85px] mt-[3px] ml-[5px] justify-center items-center px-2'
    width='56'
    height='56'
    viewBox='0 0 56 56'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
    <clipPath id='posReviewClip' transform='translate(5, 0)'>
        <circle cx='26' cy='26' r='26'/>
    </clipPath>
    <circle cx='26' cy='26' r='26' fill='#1DAB24'/>
    <g clipPath='url(#posReviewClip)' transform="translate(-2, -1)">
        <AiOutlineSmile style={iconStyle}/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The SVG contains an animation defined inside of iconStyle. It is declared inline inside of my tsx file since I have to use it in combination with a ternary operator:

```
const iconStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
        animation: click ? 'move-up 1s ease-in-out forwards' : '',
        transform: 'scale(2) translate(6px, 5.5px)',
        fill: '#fafafa',
    };
```

It is a very simply animation (icon moves from bottom to 0%), and together with the clip mask it looks like the icon appears from behind the circle it is currently in. On firefox, everything works perfect. On Chrome, however, the animation is not triggered, yet I can see the styles being applied in dev tools. The icon is much smaller and is stuck in the top left corner, whatever I do.

It only seems to occur with SVG files that I imported from react-icons. Dedicated SVG paths seem to work both fine and as expected in both browsers. I have tried to get the path from the svg from the source code from react-icons, but that does not seem to solve the issue.

Can anyone help me?

(See above for things tried)